# How to parse a string in SWIFT

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

How do i parse data from a string?
 I am trying to parse out "@usernames" and "RT" retweets from a Twitter String.

The data that comes back is like this

```
"@username hey everyone this is a random tweet #whatsup @username2 blah blah"
```

How would I go about parsing that data out? I already pull the tweet data and put it into a variable called currentTweet

Comment: show your string that you want parse

Comment: and be more explicit when describing the problem you're having - I can't see any relationship between the question and the code

Comment: I updated the description, if you could help me out now

Answer (score 0):

You use [twitter-text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text) and a [bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).